# How to loop through all values on two tables?

Tags: python, pandas

Would you do me a favor on how to do the expected result?

Initial Table A:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Ken | 500 |
| John | 600 |
| Keith | 700 |

Initial Table B:

| Period |
| --- |
| 202201 |
| 202202 |
| 202203 |

My expected table is below

| Name | Period | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ken | 202201 | 500 |
| Ken | 202202 | 500 |
| Ken | 202203 | 500 |
| John | 202201 | 600 |
| John | 202202 | 600 |
| John | 202203 | 600 |
| Keith | 202201 | 700 |
| Keith | 202202 | 700 |
| Keith | 202203 | 700 |

I believe the above questions should be answered before, but I have no idea on how to type my requirements in google. I have spent several hours on searching for it, but still don't know how to do.

Would someone help me on above?

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: Sorry, i have modified my question above. let see if it is ok to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_score = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ken', 'John', 'Keith'], 'Score':[500, 600, 700]})
df_period = pd.DataFrame({'Period':[202201, 202202, 202203]})
print(df_score)
print(df_period)
df_score['Period'] = [list(df_period['Period']) for _ in range(df_score.shape[0])]
df = df_score.explode('Period', ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Score
0    Ken    500
1   John    600
2  Keith    700
   Period
0  202201
1  202202
2  202203
    Name  Score  Period
0    Ken    500  202201
1    Ken    500  202202
2    Ken    500  202203
3   John    600  202201
4   John    600  202202
5   John    600  202203
6  Keith    700  202201
7  Keith    700  202202
8  Keith    700  202203
```

Answer (score -2):

try this it`s like join in sql
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'fooz'],

                    'Score': [1, 2, 3, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Period': [202201, 202202, 202203]})

print(df1.merge(df2, how='cross'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should add an example to this answer, rather than just a link.